# After successfully implementing Native Advanced Ads in Recycler View, app still crashes on few instances

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, admob, crashlytics

After successfully implementing `Native Advanced` Ads in `RecyclerView`, app still crashes on few instances.

**Source Code here:** [Codelabs Developers Google - Native Advanced Feed](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#0)

Attached screenshot is from Android Device - Model: Redmi 7A, Android Ver.: 9.0

[image: Native Advanced RV - Sample]

**Main Problem:** App Crash has increased drastically, after implementing Native Advanced Feed, thereby increasing the number of Uninstalls for the app.

[image: App Crash per 10k Sessions]

**What I tried:**

Firebase Robo Test on 8 Devices, all passed.

[image: Robo Test - Firebase]

No help from Google Groups Thread:

1. [Google Admob Ads Sdk](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/G9uDxBf2Rac)
2. [App freezes when Native Unified ads are loaded](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/0QDKcvK_nEk)
3. [NativeAdView.setNativeAd is slow and blocking the main thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/G9uDxBf2Rac?pli=1)

This is the `Firebase Crashlytics` Stack Trace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:11)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:26)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:70)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:1)
       at in.careerdost.quiznew.recycler_activity.recycler_archived.loadMenu(recycler_archived.java:23)
       at in.careerdost.quiznew.recycler_activity.recycler_archived.access$100(recycler_archived.java)
       at in.careerdost.quiznew.recycler_activity.recycler_archived$1.onAdFailedToLoad(recycler_archived.java:24)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzvc.zzc(zzvc.java:6)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzws.zza(zzws.java:13)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgt.onTransact(zzgt.java:22)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
       at fw.b(fw.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ai.a(ai.java:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.m.a(m.java:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.listeners.a.a(a.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.loaders.g.run(g.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at qh.a(qh.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(f.java:1)
       at qh.dispatchMessage(qh.java)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

**Update:** `onAdFailedToLoad` and `loadMenu` methods

```
private void loadNativeAds() {
        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.ad_unit_id_native_advanced));
        adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
                unifiedNativeAd -> {
                    mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                    if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                        insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        loadMenu();
                    }
                }).withAdListener(
                new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    //public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                        Log.e("RecyclerPdf", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to load another.");
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                            loadMenu();
                        }
                    }
                }).build();
        adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
    }

    private void insertAdsInMenuItems() {
        if (mNativeAds.size() <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        int offset = (mRecyclerViewItems.size() / mNativeAds.size()) + 1;
        int index = 0;
        for (UnifiedNativeAd ad : mNativeAds) {
            mRecyclerViewItems.add(index, ad);
            index = index + offset;
        }
        //loadMenu();
    }

    private void loadMenu() {
        Fragment newFragment = new recycler_view_fragment_pdf();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_pdf, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

**For calling Activity in a Fragment:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        recycler_pdf activity = (recycler_pdf) getActivity();
        assert activity != null;
        mRecyclerViewItems = activity.getRecyclerViewItems();
    }
```

**My Conclusion:** I think it is because of Slow Connection sometimes, but not sure how to implement it here.

Any help would be Appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Add methods `onAdFailedToLoad` and `loadMenu` with question .

Comment: Thanks @ADM! I have updated the question.

Comment: I have added an answer . Try and let me know

Comment: Sure @ADM! I will update and let you know accordingly. Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `AdListener` is an independent callback its not aware of the Activity's lifecycle. What happening here is in some case when `AdListener` callbacks comes back the `Activity` is already destroyed(Maybe user just pressed back button) so any Operation you make on this Activity's Context is gonna crash because its Invalid now.
That was the same problem with `AsyncTask`.

To Avoid this kind of situation check is  Activity is Alive of not before calling any further Stuff. It can be done by :-

```
public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                    if (!adLoader.isLoading() && !isFinishing()) {
                        insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        loadMenu();
                    }
                }
```

For Activity you can check it with `isFinishing()` . in Fragment you can check `getActivity()` or `isAdded()`..

Comment: Yes. I'm using `getActivity` when calling Activity into Fragment. I will test it with `&& !isFinishing()` Please give me some time, I will update you accordingly. Thanks a lot @ADM :)

Comment: Hi @ADM It is not working. This is giving me more frequent errors now, every time I Backpress, it crashes and says the Fragment has been destroyed. If you want, I can share the error summary screenshot that I captured.